# How to find external surface temperature with unknown heat transfer coefficient?

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature, power, heat-conduction

I am trying to calculate the thickness of insulation required for a certain design. The known properties are the inside temperature, target surface temperature and thermal conductivity.

From what I have seen you need either material thickness or heat transfer coefficient to calculate the other property. Also, they will both impact surface temperature. Meaning there are 3 variables that are dependant on each other with at least 2 unknowns.

How would one go about finding these values?

Here is what I have attempted so far:

I used this equation to link outside temperature and wall thickness: L=k(Ts-To)/h(To-Ta). If any of the terms are unclear please let me know.

Then got data from literature to find that often h=10. However, all the experiments were at room temperature, my ambient temperature will be significantly higher. So I'm unsure if the results will be transferable.

I tried to mathematically model the problem. I created a "target" outside temperature, then calculate L with a value of h=10.

Then use that value of L to refine h using this equation:  h=(Nu*k)/L.

Nusselt's number was calculated using Rayleigh's number, which used both L and To. The new value of h was used to calculate a new outside temperature. But this led to a completely different result compared to the experimental data. I tried iterating the equation by feeding the final temperature back into the start. But this converged to very high values of L and low values of To.

The same process was repeated but this time the target value was L, this also led to odd results as it converged to either infinity or zero.

Could my issue be that radiation hasn't been considered? I avoided it for now as I thought it would further complicate the issue.

Comment: By "heat transfer coefficient," are you referring to the convection coefficient?

Comment: @Chemomechanics Yes

Comment: Let’s see your analysis so far?

Comment: @MAShabana Sounds like you need to model the convection occurring for this setting and geometry and then estimate a convection coefficient, possibly from existing numerical, empirical, or scaling results in the literature.

Comment: @ChetMiller I have updated my question to explain what I tried so far.

Comment: @Chemomechanics the updated question shows  my attempts at mathematically modelling the problem. I also tried a finite element analysis, but this required the convection coefficient as an input from the start. Are you aware of modelling software that does not require that?

Comment: Why did you use the wall thickness as the characteristic length for the Nussult number?

Comment: If you have the target outside wall temperature, then you should have enough information to determine the outside heat transfer coefficient (assuming a vertical wall of a certain height).  That gives you the heat flux.  The L that you should use in the natural convection correlation should be the height of the wall, not the wall thickness.

Comment: @ChetMiller thank you for clarifying the L in the natural convection correlation, I was confused how thickness could change h and also depends on it.

I'm assuming that I made the same mistake with Nussult number as well. I had used   Ra=(gβ(Ts-To)L^3)/να then used the calculated value to work out the rest. 

In that case, do you know which length someone should use for a non-uniform plate?
E.g. a rectangular plate with a semi-circle on each end.

Comment: Also, you mentions that the wall is vertical. I have two horizontal walls, what would be the implication for them?

Comment: https://www.engineersedge.com/heat_transfer/horizontal_plate_natural_convection_13968.htm

Comment: @ChetMiller thank you for all the help :)